# working with strings and VbCrLf in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I need a string that I can use for page header. The problem is when i use vbcrlf then i don't know how to come back up and write.
Example:

```
dim MyStr As String = "Amount to be" & vbcrlf & "Deducted in This Month" & VbCrLf

MyStr &= "Amount Paid Last" & VbCrLf & "Month" & VbCrLf
```

This Gives me Output

```
Amount to be
Deducted in This Month
Amount Paid Last
Month
```

'---I Want the Output like this

```
Amount to be                               Amount Paid Last
Deducted in This Month                     Month
```

'Please help me to findout the solution.

Comment: what are you upto? you are using any variable for month & Amount ?

Comment: this is only for heading of a textfile.....i have the variables for amount

Comment: Your output is exactly how you have build it. There are no values appendend to the string. And you append in the wrong order respect to the expected output

Comment: So you want,"Amount to be <<Amount>> Paid, Last Deducted in This Month <<Month>>"
You should use like "Amount to be Paid=<<Amount>>, Last Deducted in This Month= <<Month>>"

Comment: I want heading--------- Amount be Deducted in This Month   ------ Amount Paid Last Month........(Note the Amount to be deducted in last month is in length so i have to wrap this...but after wrapping The Amount Paid Last Month Goes in the second line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use composite formatting in a case like this.  Be sure to read up on it in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  A key feature to take advantage of here is its ability to align the text and pad it with spaces.  The format specifier should look like `{n,w:c}` where n is the argument number, w is the width of the generated string and c is the desired format.  Use a negative value for w to align the text to the left.

So code like this:

```
    Dim ToBePaid As Decimal = 1.23
    Dim Deducted As Decimal = 0.04
    Dim PaidLast As Decimal = 2.45
    Dim PayDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim MyStr = String.Format("{0,-10:C}{1,20:C}", ToBePaid, PaidLast) + vbCrLf + _
                String.Format("{0,-10:C}{1,20:MMMM}", Deducted, PayDate)
    Console.WriteLine(MyStr)
```

Produces this output:

```
$1.23                    $2.45
$0.04                    March
```

It will only look properly aligned if you look at the file with a file viewer that uses a fixed-pitch font.